# How to retrieve IMDB movie ID from imdbpy?

Tags: python, imdbpy

The Python `imdbpy` module allows you search by movie title.

**Example:**

```py
import imdb


ia = imdb.IMDb()

search_movie = ia.search_movie('Ready Player One')
```

**Result:**

```py
[<Movie id:1677720[http] title:_Ready Player One (2018)_>, <Movie id:8183756[http] title:_"Projector" Ready Player One (2018)_>, <Movie id:13695838[http] title:_"Big Pauly Talks Movies" Ready Player One (2018)_>, <Movie id:8045574[http] title:_"Ready Player One LIVE at SXSW" (2018)_>, ...]
```

**How do grab the first `Movie id` from the results?**

**Tried:**

- While `print(search_movie[0]['title'])` brings back the title, these do not work:

  - `print(search_movie[0]['Movie id'])`
  - `print(search_movie[0]['id'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick check of the source code shows that you want `print(search_movie[0]['movieID'])` or `print(search_movie[0].getID()`.

Comment: Thank you. I'll work at reading source. Did you look [here](https://github.com/alberanid/imdbpy/blob/c416d46389465b61ed82969a6a132b72f829aac2/bin/search_movie.py#L49)?

Comment: Ah, now I see. [REF1](https://github.com/alberanid/imdbpy/blob/c416d46389465b61ed82969a6a132b72f829aac2/imdb/Movie.py#L214), [REF2](https://github.com/alberanid/imdbpy/blob/c416d46389465b61ed82969a6a132b72f829aac2/imdb/Movie.py#L93)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is pure Python and not Xytron,
Your search is returning a variable of type list and, as you found, the first result can be isolated with...

Try print(`search_movie[0]`)

The contents of `search_movie[0]` is a simple text string.
A way is to grab the digits between
`id:`
And
`[http]`

If the IMDb module cannot give you the exact format you want, you can do manipulate the result with a find to get the position of the `[http]` and assume the start of a cut will be the character number 10 (starting with 0).

```py
endCut = search_movie[0].find("[http]")

MovieID= search_movie[0][10, endCut]
```

MovieID will be a string. To make it an integer, you'll need to do
`MovieID= int(search_movie[0][10, endCut])` in the string where  or you can do it with